# How to change TinyMCE language in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco

I'm using Umbraco 4.9. I've downloaded a language pack and installed it in my Umbraco's TinyMCE. I suppose there is a tag in tinyMceConfig.config file that defines the language for richtexts, but I can't find anything. Does anyone know about that?

UPDATE:

I tried:

```
<config key="language">en</config>
```

but even the default en language option makes richtext editor disapear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language of the WYSIWYG text editor is controlled by the user login.

Under the user select the language you would like to use for the backend of Umbraco.

Out of the box it supports:

- Danish
- German
- English (uk)
- Spanish
- French
- Italian
- Korean
- Dutch
- Norwegian
- Swedish (se)
- Swedish

If the language you need is not listed there, you have a couple of options. The first option is to create a whole new translation of the Umbraco backend, this involves editing Umbraco translation files etc and and is reasonable sized task.

If you just want the TinyMCE editor translated you can hack the JS so that it uses your translation file instead of the default.

To do this you need to rename a couple of JS files and update one. Basically the principal is that you replace one of the existing languages i.e. en or fr with your own.

There are instructions on how to do this on the post on [our.umbraco.org](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/using/ui-questions/34525-TinyMCE-not-work)

I don't recommend this approach, if you are looking for new full translation of the backend then why not reach out on the [our.umbraco.org](http://our.umbraco.org) forum and see if anyone has already done the translation you are looking for or would be willing to help.